# Is it possible to ask for input inside the sails console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm currently using sails.js and I'm adding some helpers functions to the sails console because I'm lazy and I don't want to write the functions every time.

Now I would like to implement a function that ask the user for input while inside the console.

For example:

```
sails> sails.config.destroyAllUsers()
Are you sure?(Y/N)> Y
Deleted all users.
sails>
```

I've been trying to use readline, repl and prompt but the console seems to execute both repls at the same time instead of locking.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I put some time into it without any luck.

Comment: Not yet, for now I implemented the function without user input.